# The day and month value is getting flipped when excel is exported to a datatable

Tags: c#, .net, excel, datetime

```
string connectionString = String.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;""", path + new_filename);

OleDbConnection objConn = null;
System.Data.DataTable dt_sheet = null;
objConn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
objConn.Open();

dt_sheet = objConn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

string SheetName = dt_sheet.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();

if (dt_sheet.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    if (dt_sheet.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString() == Handle.ToString(SheetName))
    {
        string query = String.Format("select * from [{0}]", SheetName);
        OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, connectionString);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        dataAdapter.Fill(dt);

        //rest code 
    }
}
```

Date is not getting flipped if I do data->text to column->text but in my case date will be entered in date format compulsorily. I have gone through date flipped question in stackoverflow but it was taking a single field. I want to get whole excel in a dataTable without getting date flipped. Is there is any way to get that.Another problem is that sometime in excel date can be uploaded as just text only so in behind code I can't go for a compulsory function to flip date.
I am using visual studio 2013,C#

Comment: The best thing I can suggest is to loop through your results from the sheet and evaluate and reformat the date as needed before you fill the data table.

Comment: It would be incredibly useful if you could create a [mcve] for this.

Comment: @Enigmativity are you addressing me regarding my suggestion?

Comment: @Ortund - No, that was a comment for the OP.

Comment: @Enigmativity Actually code is not doing to much it just getting the values in dt from excel, so that it can be uploaded to DB after doing a check on every value of dt.I have used a date validator to insure it is coming in right format.But as date is getting flipped, days are getting validated by month validation.

Comment: @Ortund Sorry , I didn't get you on code basis. Do have any link or code snippet about what are you saying.

Comment: @AkshayKumar - Everyone says that they think the rest of the code is not so important, but unless we can see an obvious mistake in the code you've posted then we need to be able to run your code to see how it works. We can't run your code without it being a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the datetime values are all in the same column of your spreadsheet, it should be relatively easy to loop through the rows and reformat the date as needed:

```
if (dt_sheet.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    if (dt_sheet.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString() == Handle.ToString(SheetName))
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in dt_sheet.Rows)
        {
            row[3] = (DateTime)row[3].ToString("mm/dd/yyyy") as DateTime;
        }
        // The rest of your code goes here.
    }
}
```

I don't have time to test this code, but it should be enough to get you moving forward.

Comment: sorry but it gives an error "No overload for method 'Tostring' takes '1' argument ".

Comment: `row[3]` is an `object`. You need to cast it to `DateTime` first then call `ToString` method.

Comment: Try adding in `as DateTime;` on the end of the line. The `(DateTime) cast should take care of this though